# How to make a function that returns a dabase data with node.js and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

*I have a function getbook, that want to query the database and want to  return the database data. Is it possible?*

```
function getbook(){
  MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017", function (err, client) {
      const db = client.db('mydb')
      db.collection('books',(err,collection)=>{
       collection.find().toArray((err,items)=>{
        books = items;
       })
      })               
  })
}

console.log(getbook())
```

Comment: Can you more clearly articulate your question please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since MongoClient is a callback function, you can't simple call the function like that. There is two option

- promisify getbook() >> recommended
- add callback function when calling getbook

promisify getbook (assume the code below is wrap :

```
function getbook(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017", function (err, client) {
      if(err) {
        reject(err)
      } else {
        const db = client.db('mydb')
        db.collection('books',(err,collection)=>{
          if (err) {
            reject(err)
          } else {
            collection.find().toArray((err,items)=>{
              if (err) {
                reject(err)
              }
              resolve(items)
            })
          }
        })
      }

    })
  }
}
```

in the code block where you call the function, it has to be an async function

```
async function main() {
  const book = await getbook()
  console.log(book)
}
```

Using callback

```
function getbook(callback){
  MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017", function (err, client) {
      const db = client.db('mydb')
      db.collection('books',(err,collection)=>{
       collection.find().toArray((err,items)=>{
        callback(items)
       })
      })               
  })
}

function main () {
  getbook((book) => {
    console.log(book)
  })
}
```